# Meteor Session.get and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, session, meteor

Is there any possibility (in Meteor) to get all Session keys and match them with Regex? like

```
Session.set( /(?:^|\W)word-(\w+)(?!\w)/g , false )
```

I want set them all to false. But i know only first word in key name, and it is always the same.

Comment: Can you provide a sample string of what it looks like?

Comment: This is something like 'addTaskOpenedvfJaJebYR9PaKy84Z' but the Regex pattern isn't such big problem. Bigger problem is that I don't know how to use Session.set(..) with regex.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. You need to know all used keys and set their values one by one.

Answer (score 2):

`Session` is not designed to work with `regexp`. On the other hand you can easily use client-side collections for storing information of this type. So

```
var mySession = new Meteor.Collection(null); // null is important!

mySession.update({key: {$regexp: /* regexp */}}, {$set: {value: false}});
```

Remember that `Collection` is a reactive data-source just like `Session`, so this will behave almost identically as `Session` in terms of templates rendering. The only difference is that the data from `mySession` will be erased after hot code push. This can be fixed by using `reload` or `amplify` package but it is quite a different story.